# The integer $17$ belongs to the residue class modulo $m$ of $24$. Find $m$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Please, help me on this question. I decided, but I need to know if my answer is correct.

I thought of calculating m for the values ​​of the divisors of 24, that is, making m belonging to D (24).

So I found

$m=2 \Rightarrow \{2k+1;k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

$m=3 \Rightarrow \{3k+2;k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

$m=4 \Rightarrow \{4k+1;k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Is the question that $17\equiv 24\mod m$, and you need to find out $m$?

Comment: $17 \in \bar{a}$

Comment: @FelipeMaia What is $\bar{a}$?

Comment: @kccu Set consisting of all integers that are congruent to the integer $a\; mod\; m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition of [*residue*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Residue.html). The number $r$ in the congruence $a\equiv r\pmod m$ is called the *residue* of $a\pmod m$. In the case at hand $r=17$ and $ a=24 $.

This means that for some integer $k$ the following equality holds $24=17+km $.  You should then have $km=7$, where $ k $ and $ m $ are *positive integers*. This implies that $ m=7 $, because $7 $ is a *prime* number, that is, it has no divisors, except $ 1 $ and $7 $.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you have $24\equiv 17\pmod{m}$ if and only if $m\mid(24-17)$.

Comment: So who is $ m$?

Comment: I understood that $24 = m \cdot k + r$. 
For this reason, the question "who is $m$?"

Comment: @FelipeMaia What are the divisors of $24-17=7$? The formula “$a\mid b$” is read “$a$ is a divisor of $b$”.

Comment: You did not understand my speech. I understand the concept of divisor, otherwise it would not have said "I thought of calculating m for the values ​​of the divisors of $24$"... Anyway, what I meant is that in this situation $24=m \cdot k + r$, how to get $m$?!

Comment: @FelipeMaia You can't, in general. The problem at hand is not to compute $r$, but you have the information that $24$ and $17$ are congruent modulo $m$.

Comment: Hm.. I understand. Thanks man.